Thread blocking problems Using Quarkus Mongo Client
I use @Scheduled for my scheduled tasks , but when i start running quarkus , My program reports an error :
2024-04-22 18:47:53,352 WARN  [io.ver.cor.imp.BlockedThreadChecker] (vertx-blocked-thread-checker) Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 61335 ms, time 
limit is 60000 ms: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
        at mailto:java.base@17.0.2/sun.nio.ch.socketdispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at mailto:java.base@17.0.2/sun.nio.ch.socketdispatcher.read(socketdispatcher.java:46)
        at mailto:java.base@17.0.2/sun.nio.ch.niosocketimpl.tryread(niosocketimpl.java:261)
        at mailto:java.base@17.0.2/sun.nio.ch.niosocketimpl.implread(niosocketimpl.java:312)
        at mailto:java.base@17.0.2/sun.nio.ch.niosocketimpl.read(niosocketimpl.java:350)
        at mailto:java.base@17.0.2/sun.nio.ch.niosocketimpl$1.read(niosocketimpl.java:803)
        at mailto:java.base@17.0.2/java.net.socket$socketinputstream.read(socket.java:966)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:175)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:200)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:739)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:603)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:451)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:372)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:114)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:765)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:76)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:209)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:115)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:83)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$OperationCountTrackingConnection.command(DefaultServer.java:307)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeCommand(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:395)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeBulkWriteBatch(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:259)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.lambda$execute$2(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:203)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$$Lambda$2461/0x00000008017f45e0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$0(SyncOperationHelper.java:127)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper$$Lambda$2440/0x00000008017e6000.apply(Unknown Source)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(SyncOperationHelper.java:152)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$1(SyncOperationHelper.java:126)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper$$Lambda$2430/0x00000008017e0910.apply(Unknown Source)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(SyncOperationHelper.java:152)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(SyncOperationHelper.java:125)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.lambda$execute$3(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:188)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$$Lambda$2456/0x00000008017f3b08.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.lambda$decorateWriteWithRetries$0(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:146)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$$Lambda$2459/0x00000008017f41a0.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:67)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:207)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:77)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:173)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1085)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeUpdate(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1069)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:586)
        at com.hbt.ocs.ecbdata.emr.helper.MongoSourceHelper.upsertBson(MongoSourceHelper.java:37)
        at com.hbt.ocs.ecbdata.emr.helper.MongoSourceHelper_ClientProxy.upsertBson(Unknown Source)
        at com.hbt.ocs.ecbdata.emr.sch2curtauto.Sch2CurtAutoSvc.sch2Curt(Sch2CurtAutoSvc.java:86)
        at com.hbt.ocs.ecbdata.emr.sch2curtauto.Sch2CurtAutoSvc.sch2curtauto(Sch2CurtAutoSvc.java:57)
        at com.hbt.ocs.ecbdata.emr.sch2curtauto.Sch2CurtAutoSvc_ClientProxy.sch2curtauto(Unknown Source)
        at com.hbt.ocs.ecbdata.emr.sch2curtauto.Sch2CurtAutoController.scheduler(Sch2CurtAutoController.java:27)
        at com.hbt.ocs.ecbdata.emr.sch2curtauto.Sch2CurtAutoController_ClientProxy.scheduler(Unknown Source)
        at com.hbt.ocs.ecbdata.emr.sch2curtauto.Sch2CurtAutoController_ScheduledInvoker_scheduler_34ed21eed6585d5dae0bb13943ae530f31c5b6cd.invokeBean(Unknown Source)


Controller :
@Scheduled(every = "10s", identity = "Sch2CurtAutoController")
  void scheduler(){
    scheduler.pause("Sch2CurtAutoController");
    svc.sch2curtauto();
    scheduler.resume("Sch2CurtAutoController");
  }

Svc :
public class Sch2CurtAutoSvc {

  @Inject
  MongoSourceHelper mongosourcehelper;
  public void sch2curtauto() {

    Document query = new Document("cstatus", "1")
        .append("bdate", new Document("$lt", new Date().toInstant()));
    String schName = "emrjsonsch";

    List<Document> schData = mongosourcehelper.select(schName, query);
    
      for (Document document : schData) {
        try {
          sch2Curt(schName, document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    
  }

  InsertOneResult sch2Curt(String schName, Document schDocument) {

    schDocument.remove("cstatus");
    String type = schDocument.get("articletype").toString();
    String id = DigestUtils
        .md5Hex(type + schDocument.get("tradepartyuid").toString() + schDocument.get("articleuid").toString());
    String schRecuid = schDocument.get("recuid").toString();
    schDocument.remove("recuid");
    schDocument.append("recuid", id);`your text`
    String curtName = "emrjsoncurt4" + type;
    InsertOneResult result = mongosourcehelper.upsertDocument(curtName, schDocument);

    if (result.getInsertedId() != null) {

      Bson statusFilter = Filters.eq("recuid", schRecuid);
      System.out.println(schRecuid);
      Bson updateStatus = Updates.combine(set("cstatus", "1"));
      UpdateResult statusResult = mongosourcehelper.upsertBson(schName, statusFilter, updateStatus);
    }

    return result;
  }
  

}

Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?
Can this warning be ignored? Or maybe I have an ignore setting somewhere?

Is the scheduler method annotated with anything other than @Scheduled?
